# Засыпает бот на Telebot после небольшого простоя

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Всем здравствуйте!
Написал бота в Telegram на библиотеке Telebot, но есть проблемка, то что бот засыпает.

Например, в боте есть кнопки: **[ПОГОДА НА СЕГОДНЯ][ПОГОДА НА ЗАВТРА]**, я кликаю по кнопке **[ПОГОДА НА СЕГОДНЯ]**, бот показывает погоду, далее, появляется ещё 1 кнопка **[НАЗАД]**, если я забываю на неё кликнуть, проходит допустим минут 30, я возвращаюсь в бота и нажимаю на кнопку **[НАЗАД]**, бот уже не реагирует, приходится заново вводить команду /start. Подскажите, как можно решить данный вопрос? Заранее, спасибо, коллеги!

Answer (score 0):

Так как свой код решения Вы не предоставили, отправлю Вам разъяснение общей причины исхода при котором бот засыпает после небольшого простоя и несколько вариантов решения, учитывая Ваше описание.

Проблема заключается в том, что Telegram API требует ответа от бота в течение определенного времени (обычно не более 30 секунд). Если бот не отвечает в течение этого времени, API считает, что бот отключен, и прекращает общение с ним.

Для решения данной проблемы можно использовать методы из библиотеки Telebot, которые помогут боту оставаться активным и обрабатывать запросы даже в том случае, если пользователь не нажимает на кнопки или не отправляет сообщения в течение длительного времени.

- Использовать функцию `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`. Функция `bot.polling()` позволяет боту оставаться активным и обрабатывать запросы, но не зацикливается, что позволяет боту не засыпать. Обычно ее указывают в конце кода

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

- Использовать функцию `bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, action='typing')`. Эта функция отправляет "индикатор набора текста" пользователю, что помогает сохранять интерактивность с ботом. Ее можно интегрировать в начале исполняемой функции.

```python
bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, action = "typing")
```